# ArrayList Method Return value handling

Tags: java, arraylist

Please provide an Suggestion, if Array List method Return null value,

```
public ArrayList<String> getNewRenewals() {
    ArrayList<String> getNewStatusRenewals = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<WebElement> allRows = renewaltable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    String rowvalue = "";

    for (int row = 1; row <= allRows.size(); row++) {
        String newRenewals = driver
                .findElement(
                        By.xpath("//*[@id='tblRenewals']/tbody/tr[" + row
                                + "]/td[8]")).getText().trim();
        if ("New".equals(newRenewals)) {
            rowvalue = Integer.toString(row);
            getNewStatusRenewals.add(rowvalue);
            return getNewStatusRenewals;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Searching the table and find the row value available as "New" , if "New" available then its stored that row value in Arraylist and return the same

sometime during the Execution "New" value not available in the table, so in this situation how can i handle the return statement

and assign this return method to another Arraylist method

```
public ArrayList<String> accessNewStatusRenewals() {
    ArrayList<String> newStatus = new ArrayList<String>();
    newStatus = getNewRenewals();

    if (!newStatus.isEmpty()) {

        String newStatusRow = newStatus.get(0);

        String getID = driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//*[@id='tblRenewals']/tbody/tr[" + newStatusRow
                        + "]/td[1]")).getText();
        newStatus.add(getID);
```

so if method "getNewRenewals()" return null then how can i handle return value for this accessNewStatusRenewals() method

prabu

Comment: Try to print that value that what u getting.

Comment: Reverse the comparison if that is the only problem: `"New".equals(newRenewals)` instead of `newRenewals.equals("New")`.

Comment: I am confusing about the code. During `if` branch, there is `break`, then that means the ArrayList size is always 1 or 0? When no "new" there, I think it return empty list instead of null

Comment: What exactly is the problem? A method can return an empty list. That's perfectly fine. Why use a list when it can only contain one element is questionable, though. And returning a String when it's in fact an Integer is also questionable.

Comment: what is the problem then? You don't know how to do comparison for null?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question rightly then

```
ArrayList<String> getNewStatusRenewals = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This creating a new object so null is out of question ,so there is no problem .

One suggestion is  instead of using `break` you can `return getNewStatusRenewals` in in the end return null. So you can be aware which case is executed in the code.

```
public ArrayList<String> getNewRenewals() {
    ArrayList<String> getNewStatusRenewals = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<WebElement> allRows = renewaltable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    String rowvalue = "";

    for (int row = 1; row <= allRows.size(); row++) {
        String newRenewals = driver
                .findElement(
                        By.xpath("//*[@id='tblRenewals']/tbody/tr[" + row
                                + "]/td[8]")).getText().trim();
        if (newRenewals.equals("New")) {
            rowvalue = Integer.toString(row);
            getNewStatusRenewals.add(rowvalue);
           return getNewStatusRenewals;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: i'm calling this return with another Array list method, in this situation how can i handle this empty action

Comment: instead of calling this method in method param you may do ArrayList list=getNewRenewals();  now you can check whether list is null or have some value

Answer (score 0):

The above method will always returns a not null arraylist, which should be the case.

Effective Java 2nd Edition by Joshua Bloch
Item 43: Return empty arrays or collections, not nulls

At the client side, one may use isEmpty method and then work on result.. something like

```
    ArrayList<String> output = getNewRenewals();


    if (output.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Empty");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Empty");
                    output.get(0);
    }
```

Hope this answers..